# Method Injection - not in a controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, inversion-of-control, laravel-5.3

Inside a class I wish to inject an Interface and have the IOC resolve it.

```
public function handle(\some\interface $foo){

    $foo->bar();
}
```

The above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject an interface into a class like this:

```
interface ConnectionInjector{
    public function injectConnection( Connection $con );
}

class UserProvider implements ConnectionInjector{
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(){
        ...
    }

    public function injectConnection( Connection $con ){
        $this->connection = $con;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm I don't think you fully understand the question. I'm not trying to use the classes interface. I want to inject another interface which the IOC resolves.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a way for **Binding Interfaces To Implementations** then you can do it in `register` method of your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class as:

```
$this->app->bind('some\interface', 'some/class_implementation');
```

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations)

> A very powerful feature of the service container is its ability to bind an interface to a given implementation. For example, let's assume we have an `EventPusher` interface and a  `RedisEventPusher` implementation. Once we have coded our `RedisEventPusher` implementation of this interface, we can register it with the service container like so:

```
$this->app->bind(
    'App\Contracts\EventPusher',
    'App\Services\RedisEventPusher'
);
```

> This statement tells the container that it should inject the
>   `RedisEventPusher` when a class needs an implementation of `EventPusher`.
>   Now we can type-hint the `EventPusher` interface in a constructor, or
>   any other location where dependencies are injected by the service
>   container:

```
use App\Contracts\EventPusher;

/**
 * Create a new class instance.
 *
 * @param  EventPusher  $pusher
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(EventPusher $pusher)
{
    $this->pusher = $pusher;
}
```

Comment: In your question, you have asked for "Inside a class" and I think controllers are also classes. If you have any specific use-cases please provide in your question so that we can help you.

Comment: Ok then, my use case is any class but a controller. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It depends on how you are initializing the class. Can you provide that code?

Comment: Class is initialised via dependency injection.

Comment: The above answer does not work. it's not even an example of method injection.